# What is the meaning of `--noout` of xmllint?

Tags: xml, xmllint

I don't see the difference between the two.

```
$ xmllint --xpath '//div' --html - <<< '<html><body><div>abc</div></html>'
<div>abc</div>
$ xmllint --noout --xpath '//div' --html - <<< '<html><body><div>abc</div></html>'
<div>abc</div>
```

Could anybody let me know what the meaning of `--noout` is? The man page is not very clear on this.

```
       --noout
           Suppress output. By default, xmllint outputs the result tree.
```

Answer (score 0):

The flag `--xpath` does not return a result tree, so there is nothing to suppress.
Instead `--xpath` returns the result of the xpath expression.

You could suppress the output using `--noout` when validating a XML against a XSD,  for example.